# Why is my array switching values?

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to make a short code to switch the first and last values in an array and output a new array identical to the first array but with those values switched. After trying a few times, I realized my first (original) array kept switching its [0] value, and I can't tell why. This is the code.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int[] original={1,2,3,4};
       int[] switched=original;
       switched[0]=original[original.length-1];
       switched[switched.length-1]=original[0];
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(switched));

}

}
```

I wanted the output to be [4,2,3,1], but I always get [4,2,3,4].

Comment: Both `original` and `switched` reference the same array. Anything you do to one of them you're doing to both. You want a *new* array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some magic you should know :).

In this line : `int[] original={1,2,3,4};` you create array *{1,2,3,4}* and you store REFERENCE to it in your variable `original`

In this line : `int[] switched=original;` you copy the value of `original` which is REFERENCE to that array into the variable `switched`.

Now, you have two variables which are both referencing to the same array!

---

To create new array with same values, you can use this :

```
int [] switched = (int[])original.clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

both are reference to same array

initially

```
1,2,3,4
```

after

```
switched[0]=original[original.length-1];

4,2,3,4
```

after

```
switched[switched.length-1]=original[0];

4,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `switched` and `original` pointing to the same object.

Do:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] original={1,2,3,4};
        int[] switched={1,2,3,4};
        switched[0]=original[original.length-1];
        switched[switched.length-1]=original[0];
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(switched));
    }
}
```